# Align text between CSS grid areas

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout - for this question I will use a simple example -> 1 row, 4 columns (2 areas). 
In grid areas, I have a text with different font sizes. I would like to align the text to each other but can't figure it out.
I didn't find similar questions but maybe I searched for wrong phrases.

EDIT: Both must be aligned to the bottom line. Font-size is calculated. Code and example have been modified.

```css
.timer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "status status status timer";
}

.timer-label {
  grid-area: status;
  display: flex;
  font-size: calc(1em + 3vw);
  background-color: blue;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.timer-value {
  grid-area: timer;
  font-size: calc(1em + 9vw);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div class="timer-label">
    <span>Processing...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timer-value">
    <span>00:55</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Expected result:
I would like to have the bottom of "Processing..." text aligned to the bottom of the timer so both are in the same line (red line on print screen).

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sores/m1uhLewy/7/

Comment: try `line-height: 60px;` for the text

Comment: The font-size must remain different and it's calculated, not hardcoded. Is it ok to use line-height then?

Answer (score 2):

Make Following change in your CSS Code

```
.timer {
    align-content: start;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "status status status timer";
}

.timer-label {
    grid-area: status;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    align-items: flex-end;
    line-height: 70px; /* Add this Line */
}

.timer-value {
    grid-area: timer;
    font-size: 75px;
    background-color:green;
    line-height: 70px; /* Add this Line */
}
```

Explanation: The problem is your font size is different for the Processing text and the time causing the issue in height, You can specify the line-height property and make the design consistent. You can adjust the value of line height based on your preference.

Comment: I edited the question - font-size is calculated. Hardcoding the line-height will solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to bring the font-size of each section to the other one in order to get the same baseline. You can do it with by using pseudo element like below:

```css
.timer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "status status status timer";
}

.timer-label {
  grid-area: status;
  font-size: calc(1em + 3vw);
  background-color: blue;
}
.timer-value {
  grid-area: timer;
  font-size: calc(1em + 9vw);
  background-color: green;
}
/**/
.timer-value:before {
   content:"";
   font-size: calc(1em + 3vw);
}
.timer-label:before {
   content:"";
  font-size: calc(1em + 9vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div class="timer-label">
    <span>Processing...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timer-value">
    <span>00:55</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saw this kind of solution somewhere over the net but didn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/sores/m1uhLewy/21/

Comment: @beribazoo check my code well, removed display:flex. It won't work with it

Answer (score -3):

in class .timer-label just change align-items: center; that's it

Comment: Needs to be aligned to bottom line.