# Align different sized text in float span and adjacent span set to "display:block"?

Tags: html, css

I have two spans each with different content and different sizes - they correspond to a label and related content. This markup is generated (hence the inline styles) and I don't have any control over the kinds of elements I can use. I can't, for instance, swap out the spans for divs, but otherwise I can modify the styles and necessary.

[image: example spans]

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/nerraga/pen/XWbmrGN?editors=1100)

In order to get the "label" span to entirely fill its vertical space, I've floated it left and I've set the content block to "display:block".

Is it possible to line up the line-height of the label and the content? I'm trying to get something like the following:

[image]

I'm no css guru, but I've tried variations on inline-block, flex, etc. as alternatives to floating to no avail. I can't use absolute positioning since content and label sizes are variable.

```
<div class="se-NonEditableField se-NonEditableField_largeContent" 
     style="line-height: 77px; font-size: 64px; font-family: Arial; min-height: 77px;  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">

  <span class="se-FieldLabel se-FieldLabel_readonly se-FieldLabel_readonly_largeContent" 
        style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial; min-height: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    label</span>

  <span style="line-height: 77px; font-size: 64px; font-family: Arial; min-height: 77px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: block;">
    content</span>
</div>
```

```
.se {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: black;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
    cursor: default;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: normal;
}

.se-FieldLabel {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.se-FieldLabel_readonly {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.se-FieldLabel_readonly_largeContent {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.se-NonEditableField {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 1ch;
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-indent: -1ch;
}

.se-NonEditableField_largeContent {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: related:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59985957/8620333 (almost a duplicate)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mn768jou/

Comment: display:grid/flex/inline-block/iline-flex/inline-table/inline-grid allows vertical-align. **float and display:block  do not**  line-height can fake it for a single line. Drop float and block and pickup any other display that fits the best your visual ;)